# A sign up page with an specific user input

Tags: java

I am creating a "sign up" page in java. I want the user to only be able to enter `String` as an input. So if the user tries to enters an `Integer`, it should not appear or the user should not be able to proceed and the program indicates it to type it again by deleting his previous input. I would like you guys to help me. Please consider providing me with other solutions as well and if that is not possible showing me how to only repeat the user input will be nice as well.

Comment: what have you tried so far? it's call as validation. is it standalone app (Using swing like lib) or web app (jsp / servlet) ?

Comment: you mean a Sign up web page? If that is so, then you can use `Javascript` for validating input.

Comment: You really need to edit this question with exactly what the issue you're having is, the desired state, and details about the environment you are trying to create.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this? accepts only string value except numbers?

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Patrn {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         //input strings
        String eqn[] = { "121212"  ," abacdvc " ,"abc 123" };

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
        for(int i=0;i<eqn.length;i++){
        Matcher m = p.matcher(eqn[i]);

        if (m.find()) {

          System.out.println(eqn[i]+" contains numeric values "+m.group());
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(eqn[i]+" is valid String");
        }
       }
    }
}
```

use regular expression

[Pattern matching java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: it is showing a error on the semicolon sign besides  "Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+")". if you remove that it shows a couple more errors. I will be glad if you provide me with a improved answer. Thanks for taking your time to answer, i really appreciate it.

Comment: This code is working fine. i don't know where you stucked up.

Comment: sorry my bad, it works. But that is not what i exactly want. I want a valid scanner/user input by the user. I want the user to only be able to enter an string. Your code does not have a scanner.